# Disallow mysql UPDATE for this session

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a web hosting that do not allow me to grant privileges to users.
So I only have one usable user, with SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE privileges.

I connect to MySQL using PHP with `MySQLi`.

**Is there a way to tell either MySQL (the database itself) or `MySQLi` (the PHP object) to disallow updates/deletes only for the current session?**

The aim is to have this kind of code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQLI_IP, MYSQLI_USER, MYSQLI_PASSWORD,n MYSQLI_DBNAME);

// I have SELECT privileges so it works
$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `table`');

// This should work too because I have UPDATE privilege
$mysqli->query('UPDATE `table` SET `date`=NOW()');

// This is the "command" I'm looking for
$mysqli->disallowUpdates();

// Ok, it still works
$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `table`');

// This must not work because I told mysqli (php)/mysql (db)
// to disallow updates for this session
$mysqli->query('UPDATE `table` SET `date`=NULL');
```

Comment: Sidenote: You have an (stray) `n` inside `(MYSQLI_IP, MYSQLI_USER, MYSQLI_PASSWORD,n MYSQLI_DBNAME)` typo?

Comment: Define "for the current session". Do you mean PHP [**sessions**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/features.sessions.php)?

Comment: Privileges are user based, not session based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in any way mentioned. You need to do that logic by yourself, for example:

Grant or disallow on some condition:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['isAllowedToUpdate'] = false;
```

Do updates:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['isAllowedToUpdate']) && $_SESSION['isAllowedToUpdate']) {
  // do some updates
}
```

Comment: I though about that, but I dislike it a bit because in case of injection, I won't have any protection against the injected UPDATE. But if there is no other way, I'll stick to this solution...

Comment: @Xenos Write injection proof code, i.e. use prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: @VMai It will only be injection proof toward clients, not toward developers: it won't be safe if a (bad) developer writes `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT`, except if I do a `CustomMySQLi` class with different `select(...)` and `update(...)` methods.